# Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3000/api on a M1 Macbook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apple-m1

I am working on a project with Node.js, React.js and MongoDB.

When I send request to server, I get the following error:

> Error occurred while trying to proxy request `/api/auth/login` from `localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:6000` (ECONNRESET).

I have my client running at port 3000, server at port 6000 locally. Here is the client side proxy middleware setup code:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api/", { target: "http://localhost:6000", "secure": "false" }));
};
```

I have tried using `127.0.0.1` inplace of `localhost`, but didn't work.

The project works fine in Windows laptop. But, it is having problem with M1 Mac.

Any guidance would be of great help to me.

Comment: Is the server actually running and bound on port 6000?

Comment: @Phil Yes, the server is listening on port 6000. When I request the server I get this res:

node:events:504
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0] Error: read ECONNRESET
[0]     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
[0] Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
[0]     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
[0]     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
[0]   errno: -54,
[0]   code: 'ECONNRESET',
[0]   syscall: 'read'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed the version of Node.js to 14.9.0 and it worked.

These are the solutions found in the internet that didn't work for me:

> - Changing node.js version to other stable version 16 or 18
> - specifying an IPv4 address like this on server (because I can see my server was running on IPv6): `server.listen(13882, "0.0.0.0", function() { });`
> - Removing proxy entry from the Package.json file
> - Updating to `{target: "http://localhost:6000/"}` OR `{target: "https://localhost:6000/"}` OR `{target: "http://127.0.0.1:6000"}` OR
>   `{'http://[::1]:6000'}` OR `{app.use(proxy("/api/", {target:"http://localhost:6000",secure: false,changeOrigin: true}));}`

I have this entry in package.json file `"proxy": "http://localhost:6000"`

This is my setupProxy.js file

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api/", { target: "http://localhost:6000" }));
};
```

Answer (score 14):

I got the same error using M1.

This code started working correctly for me.

`http://localhost:3000/` -> `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

server.js

```js
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

const PORT = 9090;
const HOST = "0.0.0.0";

const app = express();

app.use(
  createProxyMiddleware("/", {
    target: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/",
  })
);

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

packege.json

```js
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

- node v18.11.0
- npm 8.19.2

Server at "http://127.0.0.1:3000/" - default configuration for [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) ("react-scripts": "^5.0.1")